# Reduce 3.3 V-8.4 V signal to 3.3 V input

Tags: level-shifting, ttl

I have a digital input signal which can use anywhere between 3.3 V and 8.4 V to signal "1", and I need to make this safe for a 3.3 V input on a microcontroller (RP2040).

I currently have a working circuit, using a 2N7002K MOSFET.

[image]

The inversion is easy to deal with in software.

The issue with this circuit is that the input line is on an exposed connector, and the MOSFETs appear to be very sensitive to [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge).  The datasheet claims 2 kV ESD protection, but I've killed several of them now.

So, I'm now looking at adding external ESD protection on the gate, but the parameters are reasonably tight: as I understand it I need a standoff voltage of > 8.4 V and a breakdown voltage of < 20 V (FET V<sub>GS</sub> *maximum*).

Is there a better way?

There seem to be few options for logic-level converters that can cope with more than 5 V inputs.  I've got several of these inputs to handle, so an IC with with multiple lines would be ideal.

The signal on the data line is UART running at up to 400 kbit/s, so 2.5 µs pulse width.  The data line is a shared bus with multiple transmitters and uses a weak pull-up (around 5 kΩ) to enable idle line detection, so it's important that the input is high impedance to avoid interfering with this.

Comment: It actually sounds like you could use a RS232 transceiver in place of the MOSFET. Admittedly a weird solution, but they have great ESD protection, can handle a wide range of input voltages, give out a nice clean 3V3 and are widely available. Some version of the old school MAX232 but with 100nF caps and 3V3 logic levels .

Comment: Interesting suggestion, although I perhaps oversimplified the signal I'm dealing with.  It's actually either a 3.3V UART signal, or it's a higher voltage PWM signal, and I need to read it either way.  The PWM is only 200Hz so rather slower.

Comment: It wouldn't matter. Such transceivers are very fast switching. What you can't get from it is the other way around: 3V3 to some exotic 8.4V

Comment: Why not simply a resistor & diode to clamp to a 3.3V supply?

Comment: I assume you mean a zener diode?  I think this won't work because I need it to work with no voltage drop (3.3V in, 3.3V out), so there's no voltage to drop across the resistor.  At, say, 3.4V in, we still want 3.3V out so we need a very small resistor to achieve the Zener current, which gives us a very low impedance input with very high current at higher voltages.

Comment: No, a [normal diode clamp](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Diode_clamp_protection_circuit.png)

Comment: That will clamp to 3.3V + diode's Vf.  For a 1N4148 that's 0.5V @ 0.1mA which is more than the specified 3.3V  + 0.3V for the input.

Comment: The specified 3.3V + 0.3V limit is for a zero resistance source. Add a series resistor between the clamp and the digital input to limit the current to below the maximum allowed input current

Answer (score 9):

> *So, I'm now looking at adding external ESD protection on the gate, but
> the parameters are reasonably tight: as I understand it I need a
> standoff voltage of > 8.4V and a breakdown voltage of < 20V (FET Vgs
> MAX).*

Sounds like a 12 volt zener diode or TVS would likely do the job. You can limit current into the zener/TVS (connected between gate and source) with a series 1 kΩ resistor: -

[image]

Comment: TVS = [Transient-voltage-suppression diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode)

Answer (score 4):

A BJT is more robust (and less expensive), especially if you protect it against negative base voltage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faf3HW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transition is around 1.5V.

If you are concerned about very high voltages (kV), R2 needs to be large enough that it can't arc over and won't fail from the pulse. You can lower R1/R2 (eg. to 10K each) if you're more concerned about an open input picking up noise than kV.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand that BJTs are more robust, but if I understand the above correctly, Vbe will still see half of any ESD spike.  Also, when I tried simulating this circuit, it didn't seem able to cope with higher speed signals.

Comment: Reduce the resistors for higher speed. The base sees only +/- 0.7V or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I lower the resistors I think the input will have insufficient input impedance for the data line its reading from, which relies on a weak pull-up to detect idle line.  I've made a slight edit to the original post to clarify this requirement.

Comment: Assuming a collector resistor of 2.2K or 3.3K and base resistors of 10K series , 100K base-emitter the pullup could be as high as 20 or 30K and still work very reliably. You can actually eliminate the 100K since the only reason I put it there is to have a defined 'open' state, and it's fighting the one you want to impose.

Comment: Thank you for posting this update.  The issue I see with this circuit is what happens to Vin if V1 is removed completely.  The voltage of Vin will be pulled down to around 2.4V which may be too low for the other devices on the data line to conclude that the line is idle.  The data line that I'm trying to sample relies on it being pulled high by the 5K pull-up in one of the other devices when there is no other signal.

Answer (score 3):

The revised circuit below should cover the static problem and circuit requirements you're describing, though the R2 and R3 values may need to be adjusted for your particular input conditions.

As you had it, the Q1 gate was a voltage-sensitive capacitance going directly to a board connector. During handling, that's prone to ESD damage, as you've found. You can try to improve handling but it's much better to design it out wherever possible. Benefits assembly staff, any field service engineers etc.

**Series resistor R3** reduces the maximum gate charge/discharge current and decouples the gate driver from the effects of the gate-drain capacitance during switching. The latter is probably not such a problem here but the resistor should be fitted.

**Q1 gate pull-down R2** serves two purposes. One is to put Q1 into a known state if the board is powered with the input unconnected, such as in test or lab' work. The second is as a static discharge path during handling and leaks the charge down to zero. As an aside, before TVS diodes were available and cheap, I designed this resistor onto all boards where a static sensitive MOSFET terminal or IC pin goes straight to a connector. It was very successful and we had few mass-production or field service board failures and none tracked down to ESD.

To solve your problem, you should **use a bi-directional TVS diode directly across the connector pins**. This must be fitted as close to the connector and up the shortest tracks possible. A TVS diode must have nothing in series with it.

As their name states, Transient Voltage Suppression (TVS) diodes are for discharging transients and quickly dissipating that energy within themselves. The TVS diode has a max. transient repetition rate to keep its average power dissipation below their rated power. This is all detailed/specified in the TVS datasheet.

TVS diodes are not for continuous conduction of unwanted signals and have an imprecise conduction threshold voltage. Therefore the TVS diode voltage rating should be above what the connector pin could be driven with but with a max. threshold voltage below the maximum Q1 gate voltage. Make sure you don't just take the threshold voltage from the TVS diode's part number. Check the min. and max. thresholds in the datasheet, using those to select the part. I have got many such designs cleanly through EMC and testing standards approvals.

When the static charge drops below the TVS diode's rated threshold, the TVS will stop conducting and R2 will discharge what remains towards zero.

*(schematic has wrong TVS diode symbol, correct one not in library)*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4NHZh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.  Can you give any details on what to consider when calculating R2 and R3?  The input signal is stated as having a "weak pull-up" in order facilitate idle line detection, so I'm a bit concerned about the effect that R2 may have.  Also, is there a reason to want to turn off Q1 when disconnected, other than to avoid meaningless signals on the output?    I've found a TVS with stand-off voltage of 12V and a clamp voltage of 19V, which I think should be suitable.   (minor typo I think "series resistor R2" should be "R1")

Comment: You're very welcome. TVS sounds good. Have clarified 'Q1 off' but is as you guessed. Your weak pull-up will have a max value spec'd somewhere, sometimes a hunt to find it with some parts. But doesn't matter as the UART will drive the line HIGH (mark) when idle, not leave it internally pulled HIGH. Unless you have some multi-UART Tx line sharing going on? In that case a pull-down is fine. How many receive devices are connected?

Comment: Yes, there's line sharing.  There are two other devices that can both transmit, although the protocol is designed to cope with more.  My device is RX only.  I've just done a bit of empirical testing, and the "weak pull-up" appears to be around 5k6.  220k would pull the idle line down by just under 0.1V which is fine, but presumably with the TVS present, this could comfortably be a bit higher?  Although it's not really an issue as the system appears to work just fine even with 15k pulling idle down to 2.4V.

Comment: Those internal pull-ups/downs have very big tolerances. On some MCUs, it's +100/-50% so design around those figures, consider for 10K. Is your 5K6 on one device or for the two Tx masters in parallel. Was empirical testing loading them with, say, 2K2 then measuring the voltage drop, which I'd do? A 0.1 V drop is beyond fine, level restoration is a benefit of digital logic, so 220K can stay and do get R3 in. Btw, the site isn't for online personal support so we'll go to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134156/discussion-between-tonym-and-pdw) if you've more debug-talk.

Answer (score 1):

Diode clamps with current limiting are effective. R1 limits the signal and ESD current through the diodes, and  R2 limits the residual current through the internal clamp diodes in your MCU to a level its internal clamps should easily handle.

R1 also limits your speed, but you don't seem to need Mbit/s rates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBafms.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you.  I think this approach may work for me. I've seen similar circuits with schottky diodes and no R2, as with the lower turn-on, the voltage stays within the input spec.  Is there a reason to prefer your arrangement?

Comment: @pdw Even a Schottky can have a substantial forward voltage during an ESD transient. Limiting the current and absorbing the energy with R2 generally makes sense. Schottky diodes are less reliable, a major problem in the past, but perhaps not so much in the 21st century.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a bipolar transistor in this configuration for example to translate between 1.8V and 3.3V.

[image]

The problem with this kind of configuration is that I've found it useful only with slow baudrate (100kbps more or less).
You're talking about 400kpbs and in my opinion this is a job for a transceiver compatible with 8.5V levels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an optocoupler?

Many of them are in the "on" state with as little as 1mA flowing through the internal LED, but can handle up to 20mA or more. So with a simple current limiting resistor of chosen good value for your minimum required voltage for "on", you should get a good range.

I have used this setup for digital input channels in industrial applications where the input voltage required ranged from 12V to 36V, and it worked perfectly fine for all those voltages. For safety, you can add a zener after the resistor, in parallel with the LED (internal to opto-coupler), to absorb transients or protect for higher than designed voltages (or to give some more range for extra high voltage input).

You can do something like below, just choose a zener with a Vz similar to the LED on voltage at low currents.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the TLP291 rise and fall times vs the input signal requirements?

Comment: No, but as I said in my description, it is just an example circuit. However, from the back of my mind, I recall that I used it in an MDB application where the baud rate was 9600 - so it should be fine.

Comment: From the question: `The signal on the data line is UART running at up to 400kbps, so 2.5us pulse width` i.e. 40 times faster than 9600 bps. I think you should check.