# To what voltage rail should the TVS be pulled up?

Tags: usb, ldo, tvs

Suppose that we need to create a board based on a USB-UART IC with the integrated LDO (5.0->3.3). Also suppose that we need an external discrete TVS IC on D+/D- lines.

To what voltage rail should the TVS be pulled up?

- If this is the 5.0V rail, there is a possibility to set on D+/D- lines 5.0-5.6V which the TVS does not cut. But also D+/D- lines can probably stand with the 5.0-5.6V impulse and a 5kV impulse will be reject for sure.
- If this is the 3.3V rail, the integrated LDO power might be too low to reject an impulse. But also blocking capacitors can reject an impulse without LDO overload.

So what is the best rail for the TVS power input (if we use only the integrated LDO) and why? For example, which TVS shall I use: [824015](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/824015.pdf) TVS on 5.0V or [824013](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/824013.pdf) TVS on 3.3V?

Comment: The answer depends on which exact TVS component you will use, and whether it even clips the data lines to supply voltage at all. Do you have a specific TVS in mind you can link a data sheet?

Comment: The TVS diodes go across the signal that can get an ESD and the ground or current return path for it. As an aside, TVS diodes sometimes get seen as magical Zener diodes on this site and in engineering. And Zener diodes get seen as magical perfect voltage drops. TVS diodes have a rough and imprecise cut-in voltage and are only for dissipating infrequent ESDs into themselves, for connection directly across a connector. [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/608564/115257) explains that more.

Comment: "The answer depends on... Do you have a specific..." The general approach to answears that depend on several conditions is describing two variants with their conditions. For example "The TVS should be connected to 5.0V if X, and it sould be connected to 3.3V if Y". But to formally clarify the question, let's assume that it is a 824015 TVS (we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/824015.pdf)

Comment: "The TVS diodes go across the signal that can get an ESD and the ground or current return path for it" Yes-yes. I already read on Wikipedia what TVS is. Now I whant to know what rail should I use (well, that is exactly what is written in the question).

Comment: Oh, great, you know all about it. Then you have no question, you've just 'yes-yes'd the solution.

Comment: There's a lot of terminology confusion in your question, and it might make things clearer if you add a schematic of the specific configuration(s) you're referring to. For example a "discrete TVS" is usually a single 2-terminal component which is connected between the data line and Ground - there's no additional voltage rail connected. In addition to that, you seem to be treating your LDO as if it's going to actively clamp  any injected current to prevent the rail from rising above its normal voltage, and for the vast majority of linear regulators that's a false assumption.

Answer (score 1):

The application notes for your specific TVS (824015) indicates the TVS supply should be the 5V VBUS in order to work in the rated specs which make it suitable for USB.

As the parameters are not given in conditions where VDD is 3.3V then this is not intended operation. It may work just fine but if you do so you are on your own.

And then it can't protect the regulator input side if it is not connected to 5V VBUS.

Also the internal structure is such that the VDD cannot be left unconnected.

If you want 3.3V protection then this may not be the right component.

But also remember that if 5V supply with 1 or 2 amps of current gets connected to USB data pin, what can you really do to protect something from that, so the TVS for ESD protection may be completely fine for you.

EDIT: So new link you gave had a better datasheet which explictly mentions below 5V operating range, but the parameters are still only given at 5V supply, not at 3.3V supply, so they are not known. For high speed buses like USB, additional capacitance may degrade the waveform (eye diagram) beyond specs so for all purposes for USB, the application notes where VDD is 5V still apply.

Comment: "As the parameters are not given in conditions where VDD is 3.3V then this is not intended operation. It may work just fine but if you do so you are on your own."  This argument is more literary than electronic. Do you have physical arguments that would say that some TVS which works on 5.0 volts may or may not works at 3.3 volts? Because the Wurth Elektronik site (https://no.rs-online.com/web/p/tvs-diodes/7546231) says that the 824015 TVS array have "Working Voltage 3.3V, 5V and 12V".

Comment: Well you did not point me to that web page. And what you quote applies to the whole series/family of TVS arrays, not this specific component. If you look at the specifications, this specific TVS would explode if subjected to 12V, as it's rated for 8.5V max clamping voltage. And that page links to better datasheet which does specifically say 3.3V is supported.

Comment: "And what you quote applies to the whole series/family" my fault. Sorry. There is a 3.3 version of this TVS (we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/824013.pdf) So I will update the question with two exact models of TVS.